# User organic groups for paid elearning courses?

Tags: organic-groups

I don't know very much about the [Organic Groups](https://www.drupal.org/project/og) module.

I have a client that is interested in a course learning system and have that content restricted by groups. Each paid user would checkout and purchase this course.

Would organic groups be good for this particular feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set Organic Groups to be visible only to users of certain roles. And with the uc_roles module in [Ubercart](http://drupal.org/project/ubercart), you can create products which grant users a certain role.

There's also a module that makes it possible to sell Organic Group membership to one or more groups when a user purchases a particular product: [UC OG Subscribe](http://drupal.org/project/uc_og_subscribe)

Depending on what exactly the course learning system would be about, the og could be a good fit. Even without it, though, you can always restrict access to content through core roles, or [ACL](http://drupal.org/project/acl) and the likes.

Comment: Is there something like this for drupal 7 and commerce?

Comment: I can't seem to find the OG Subscribe or any integration module at all. However, both [Drupal Commerce](http://drupal.org/project/commerce) and [Organic Groups](http://drupal.org/project/og) have deep integration with [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules), which I recommend to implement the business logic of your application. E.g. when customer pay for a course product, allow them access to the course content.